# What does an exit value of -1 mean when compiling and how to debug it?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am a C++ beginner. For some reason I cannot find a page with error codes and what they mean. Often my eclipse does this:

[image]

Does this -1 rather than 0 mean the same thing all the time? A segmentation fault perhaps? Or is it just a general "we didn't reach the end of the program" error?

Right now I put cout statements before and after every line until I find where it stops running. Is there somewhere specific I should look when seeing this -1?

Comment: Run your program under a debugger to see where and why the program terminates. Any part of the code can call `std::exit(-1)` or similar to terminate the program with exit code `-1`. Putting output statements between lines of codes is a very poor debugging approach. (Although sometimes helpful.)

Comment: When a program spits out a special-system-wide error code it's usually not in a widely used range.  The numbers selected are out in the boonies where they won't are unlikely to get in the way of one of the program's user-defined error codes. For example Microsoft's access violation error code is out around minus one billion.

Comment: Eclipse's debugger front-end's pretty good. Use it to step through the program to help you narrow down where it's failing. If death is not expected, uncaught exception or fatal signal, it should stop right where the program failed and allow you to poke around at the backtrace to see how the program wound up in dire straights. Use the information gathered to figure out where you want to put breakpoints on the next run to stop the program before it dies and watch the run-up to death for more information or to monitor contributors.

Comment: ***Does this -1 rather than 0 mean the same thing all the time?*** A 0 should indicate that the program terminated without issue.